# Ruby Time.new giving time zone offset of 14 minutes

Tags: ruby, time, zone

When I create a time object in Ruby 1.9.2 with a date earlier than 1 September 1919, the time zone is set to +0014 rather than to the system zone (+0100) or UTC. Now that I discovered the problem being the early date, and since all I want is a time without a date, I will just use a recent date. But does anyone know why this happens?

```
ruby-1.9.2-p0 :034 > Time.new(1919,9,1,0,0,0)
=> 1919-09-01 00:46:24 +0100 
ruby-1.9.2-p0 :035 > Time.new(1919,8,31,23,59,59)
=> 1919-08-31 23:59:59 +0014 
ruby-1.9.2-p0 :036 > Time.new(1919,8,31,1,0,0)
=> 1919-08-31 01:00:00 +0014
```

Comment: `Time.new(1919,9,1,0,0,0)` => `ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (6 for 0)`

Comment: I don't see that happening at all: `>> Time.new(1919,9,1,0,0,0) => 1919-09-01 00:00:00 -0500 >> Time.new(1919,8,31,23,59,59) => 1919-08-31 23:59:59 -0500 >> Time.new(1919,8,31,1,0,0) => 1919-08-31 01:00:00 -0500`. I'm on ruby 1.9.2 on Windows.

Comment: I should also note that I'm on ruby 1.9.2p180, so maybe it's a problem that was fixed between your p0 and p180?

Comment: Ha I forget to switch from 1.8.7 :) Same thing: everything works perfect

Comment: Thanks, everyone. Since this appears to be a quirk with my system, I'm just not going to worry about it. I'm using Ubuntu 10.04 32-bit running in VirtualBox under Windows 7.

Answer (score 0):

Echoing what others are commenting on: there is no reproducible problem here with the information you have provided. On Windows 7, 64-bit:

```
irb(main):001:0> Time.new(1919,8,31,23,59,59)
#=> 1919-08-31 23:59:59 -0600

irb(main):002:0> RUBY_DESCRIPTION
#=> "ruby 1.9.2p180 (2011-02-18) [i386-mingw32]"
```

On Ubuntu 10.04, 32-bit:

```
ruby-1.9.2-p136 :001 > Time.new(1919,8,31,23,59,59)
#=> 1919-08-31 23:59:59 -0600

ruby-1.9.2-p136 :002 > RUBY_DESCRIPTION
#=> "ruby 1.9.2p136 (2010-12-25) [i686-linux]"
```

...and on your exact patch level:

```
ruby-1.9.2-p0 :001 > Time.new(1919,8,31,23,59,59)
#=> 1919-08-31 23:59:59 -0600

ruby-1.9.2-p0 :002 > RUBY_DESCRIPTION
#=> "ruby 1.9.2p0 (2010-08-18) [i686-linux]"
```

Please provide your OS version and bit-level for additional help.